# Front tyre size - is 1.9" a good option?

Tags: tire

I have in my bike a 1.9" tyre in the front wheel and a 2.2" in the rear. Is it safe to use this tyre sizes?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, if it fits the rim OK.

Comment: While the specific tire sizes in the duplicate question are different, its answers are still applicable to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match tire sizes if you want - its relatively common. You just need to make sure that the tires fit on the rim and to a lesser extent are [not too thin or too wide for the rim](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width). This is often done for different tire clearances in the front and back, for example.